# Fetch subdocument in mongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb-compass

I want to fetch the subdocument from the document, i.e level2, level3 and level4.
Is it possible to fetch single object of level1 array, level2 and so on.

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "timestamp": "2023-08-24T23:05:00.603674963"
  "level1": [
    {
      "field11": "value11",
      "level2": [
        {
          "field21": "value21",
          "level3": [
            {
              "field31": "value31",
              "level4": [
                {
                  "field41": "value41",
                },
                {
                  "field42": "value42",
                },
                {
                  "field43": "value43",
                },
                {
                  "field44": "value44",
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "field32": "value32",
              "level4": [
                {
                  "field41": "value41",
                },
                {
                  "field42": "value42",
                },
                {
                  "field43": "value43",
                },
                {
                  "field44": "value44",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
    "field21": "value22",
    ..... 
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried below in "Project" options. which gives me single object from level1 array but from level2, I am unable to get single object.

```
{level1: {$elemMatch: {field11: 'value11'}}, 
timestamp: 1, 
_id: 1}
```

The above results: single object from level1, but I also want single object from level2, level3 and so on.

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "timestamp": "2023-08-24T23:05:00.603674963"
  "level1": [
    {
      "field11": "value11",
    .....
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried below, which does not work.

```
{level1: {$elemMatch: {field11: 'value11', 
        level2: {$elemMatch: { field21: 'value21'}}}}, 
timestamp: 1, 
_id: 1}
```

Thanks!